# Where is the correct place to put some preparatory code in CakePHP's architecture?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some things called Nodes, and they're HABTM-related among themselves. Each individual relation is specified by the user on the front-end.

When creating a new node, the front-end UI sends data in the form of:

```
$exampleData = [
  'Node' => [
    'title' => 'The title of a new node',
    'body' => 'The body of a new node'],
  'NodeRequireNode' => [ // This is the HABTM-relation
    0 => [
      'title' => 'The title of a required node'],
    1 => [
      'title' => 'The title of another required node']];
```

I need to resolve the titles of the required nodes to their IDs in the database before I can save the relation. That is, I need data like this:

```
$exampleData = [
  'Node' => [
    'title' => 'The title of a new node',
    'body' => 'The body of a new node'],
  'NodeRequireNode' => [ // This is the HABTM-relation
    0 => [
      'required_id' => 34],
    1 => [
      'required_id' => 82]];
```

This is safely possible, since no two Nodes may have the same title. The question is, where should I do this resolving?

At first, I did it in my `NodesController`:

```php
// app/Controller/NodesController.php

public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = $this->request->data;

    $thereExistRequiredNodes = (count($data['NodeRequiringNode']) > 0);
    if ($thereExistRequiredNodes) {
      // Some long, clumsy code to do the thing. Removed for brevity.
    }

    $this->Node->create();
    $this->Node->saveAssociated($data)
  }
}
```

I didn't like this because it created a lengthy method. I briefly considered simply breaking it apart into helper methods, but I've read that I should be trying to make my controllers thin and my models fat. So instead I tried to refactor the resolving code into my `NodeRequiringNode` model:

```php
// app/Model/NodeRequiringNode.php

// This method takes care of a couple forms the data might come in, relying on
// the protected method beneath it to do the actual work.
public function prepareRequiredNodesWithTitlesForSave($requiredNodes) {    
  if(isset($requiredNodes['title'])) {
    $requiredNodes = $this->_prepareRequiredNodeWithTitleForSave($requiredNodes);
  } elseif (isset($requiredNodes[0])) {
    foreach ($requiredNodes as $index => &$requiredNode) {
      $requiredNode = $this->_prepareRequiredNodeWithTitleForSave($requiredNode);
    }
  }

  return $requiredNodes;
}

protected function _prepareRequiredNodeWithTitleForSave($requiredNode) {
  $title = $requiredNode['title'];
  unset($requiredNode['title']);

  $conditions = ['title =' => $title];
  $required_id = $this->Node->field( // This line is a problem
    'id',
    $conditions);

  $requiredNode['required_id'] = $required_id;

  return $requiredNode;
}
```

This seems better, but it doesn't work. The line I marked above tries to use the `Nodes` model, which doesn't seem to be available from the `NodeRequiringNode` model.

So now I'm confused. The task of resolving titles to IDs seems janitorial, the sort of thing that ought to be purview of the model, while controllers focus on the business logic. Yet I can't do it from a model object because the model object needs to get data from another model, which is something only controllers should be doing.

How then should I architect this part of my program? Please note, this is specifically in the realm of CakePHP, *not* MVC in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a call to a controller to me, more like a call to [**`Model::field()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_field), so you are not actually trying to access a controller, but just another model?

Obviously the models are related, as far as I understand it's `Node HABTM Node` where `NodeRequireNode` is the alias for the association?

Anyhow, since the models are related it's perfectly fine that they access each other, that's why CakePHP automatically creates appropriate properties with references to the related models, ie that's how it's ment to work in CakePHP.

If possible I'd change the frontend so that it passes IDs instead of titles (that's how CakePHPs auto-magic provided by the form helper works btw), but If I'd need to resolve the titles, then, since the model is actually resolving itself, I'd properly prepare the data from within the `Node` model, either in the [**`beforeSave()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) and/or [**`beforeValidate()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate) (in case validation needs the IDs) callback, or in a custom or overridden save method.

**update** Regarding your additional question in the comments - I'm not 100% sure how it's ment, but let's say no, associated model references are created on models only. When loading a model into a controller (whether it's explicitly using [**`loadModel()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel) or implicitly by CakePHPs auto-magic), only a reference to that specific model is created (where the model itself will hold the references to the associated models).

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models**

Comment: You're right, I'm using Model::field(). And you are correct in your understanding of the association.

Your third paragraph--is CakePHP supposed to be creating references to associated models in the model objects as well as the controller objects? It's from the model object that I want to access another model.

I'll give close consideration to the callback methods you mentioned, as well as consider putting the resolution on the UI. That, too is certainly possible. If you can edit your answer to address my question above, I'll mark yours as accepted.